# Problem returning unsigned char value from C++ dll to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, dllimport

In the following example, I try to concatenate two unsigned chars(which is the requirement) by passing the values to a C++ dll and return a single string. The output I'm getting is not right.

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;   
using System.Text;

class HelloWorld
{
    [DllImport("cpp_func.dll")]

    public static extern IntPtr concat_fun(byte[] a,byte[] b, int c, int d);

    static void Main()
    {
        int x,y;
        IntPtr return_value;
        string hello = "hello", world = "world", final;
        byte[] hel = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(hello);
        byte[] wor = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(world);
        x = hel.Length;
        y = wor.Length;
        return_value = concat_fun(hel, wor, hel.Length, wor.Length);
        final = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(return_value);
        Console.WriteLine("Concatenated string:" +final);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I've declared them as byte[], since that's how native type uint8_t is represented in .NET(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/type-marshaling)
I've passed the two byte array along with their lengths as parameters.

C++:

```
_declspec(dllexport) unsigned char * concat_fun(unsigned char a[], unsigned char b[], int d, int e) {
    int i, ind = 0;
    unsigned char c[20];

    for (i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        c[ind] = a[i];
        ind++;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        c[ind] = b[i];
        ind++;
    }
    return c;
}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

`Concatenated string:????????????????`

How do I get the concatenated string?
Note: Getting input as an unsigned char for the dll function parameter, is a requirement
I know I'm making some trivial mistake here, since I'm just a beginner.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with C#, and everything to do with not realizing that `c` is a local variable that has gone out-of-scope.  Did your compiler warn you about this?  If so, this is why you don't ignore warnings.  Now how to properly return a string from an exported DLL function is another issue, and there are several answers to that.

Comment: The C# code should have provided the output `byte[]` buffer to write the concatenated string into to the DLL function.  However your current function signature has no parameter for this.   In other words, the DLL function should not be the one responsible for creating the buffer.  If you did that, then the return of a local variable becomes a moot point.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions here on this topic. Your real problem is not doing sufficiently robust research. There are lots of other issues in your code. The local variable return. The misuse of unsigned char which is for binary data not text. The lack of care for possible buffer overrun. The text encoding mismatch. To be frank you will need to brush up some fundamentals before you can expect to code this interop properly, and I mean that in a hopefully constructive way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The memory for *c* array is allocated in the *concat_fun* function and has a scope and lifetime of this function, so the memory is released when you leave the function body.
Try to allocate *c* array in the calling function Main or use dynamic memory allocation: new/delete or malloc/free in concat_fun.

Comment: There are much safer ways than leaving the responsibility of allocating memory to the C++ code.  The client could simply pass a buffer to be filled in by the C++ code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, isn't this what I suggested with "Try to allocate c array in the calling function Main"? "Allocate" doesn't mean only "dynamically allocate". Static and stack allocation is allocation, as well.

Comment: My point is that the DLL (the C++ code) need not allocate anything, and that is the way most, if not all Windows API functions operate.  All buffers, including output buffers, are supplied by the client (in this case, it is the C# code), and the C++ code merely writes into the output buffer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, it depends. Sometimes one just can't allocate in client, for example when DLL should own the allocated memory by some reason. This is more architectural and not related to this question.
Again, I suggested this (allocate the memory in the module Main) option as the first one, so I don't understand why you repeat it. My response covers both options.